# drush core-config causes 'Permission denied'

Tags: drush

When I use command as follow:

```
drush core-config
```

and then enter

```
1
```

a error displayed:

```
sh:/etc/php.ini: Permission denied
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit a system level file (ex. /etc/php5/cli/php.ini) using Drush and you don't have access to it at your current permission level. You need to login using an account with higher permissions or use sudo.

Comment: sorry,I use root instead,but it still not work.